# Meteor and iron router, wait on login

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a `login` route. I made this hook on before the action :

```
onBeforeAction: function() {

    console.log(Meteor.user())
    console.log(this.route.name)

    // If the user is not logged and if we are not on the login page
    // Redirect the user to the login page
    if( !Meteor.user() && this.route.name !== 'login' ) {
        Router.go('login');
    };

    // If the user is logged, take him out of the login page
    if( Meteor.user() && this.route.name === 'login' ) {
        Router.go('newsletters.index');
    };
}
```

But what about the login in time ?

I would like to make the router wait if `Meteor.loggingIn()` is true. The `waitOn` is about the subscriptions and did not work.

I'm pretty sure some else did that before :)

Comment: What do you need this for? Logging time is usually pretty short and doesn't involve loading many routes :-)

Comment: I have a redirection, so is the user arrive on the website on a `post route` for instance and is logging in, he will be redirected on the `login route`. Because I redirect if `Meteor.user()` returns false. I could add a logging in condition in the redirection, but what if the login fails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use...
 **Iron-Router** ($meteor add cmather:iron-router) and
 **Accounts-entry** ($ meteor add joshowens:accounts-entry). 

You can check in Git Hub
 https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry 
 https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router

For configuration, you must create in the client folder one archive, for example, config.js

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    AccountsEntry.config({
      logo: 'logo.png',                  // if set displays logo above sign-in options
      homeRoute: '/',                 // mandatory - path to redirect to after sign-out
      dashboardRoute: '/dashboard',      // mandatory - path to redirect to after successful sign-in
      profileRoute: 'profile',
      passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL',
      language: 'en',
      showOtherLoginServices: true,     // Set to false to hide oauth login buttons on the signin/signup pages. Useful if you are using something like accounts-meld or want to oauth for api access
      extraSignUpFields: [{             // Add extra signup fields on the signup page
        field: "name",                           // The database property you want to store the data in
        name: "This Will Be The Initial Value",  // An initial value for the field, if you want one
        label: "Full Name",                      // The html lable for the field
        placeholder: "John Doe",                 // A placeholder for the field
        type: "text",                            // The type of field you want
        required: true                           // Adds html 5 required property if true
       }]
    });
  });
```

after that you must add in the folder lib/router.js add this code below,

```
var mustBeSignedIn = function(pause) {
    AccountsEntry.signInRequired(this);
};

Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {
    except: ['entrySignIn', 'entrySignUp', 'entryForgotPassword', 'layout', 'home']
});
```

This is la solution that I use in this moment.

Comment: you should alsa except : entryResetPassword